# google translate android

Tags: java, android

На сколько мне известно, google translate api - сам по себе платный.

Есть какие-нибудь библиотеки под android для бесплатного перевода слов?

Comment: У яндекса API бесплатный. До 2млн символов в месяц, вроде.

Comment: https://github.com/dejurin/php-google-translate-for-free https://toster.ru/q/16856

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у яндекса каличный api

Comment: @Санаев, я не сравнивал, так что не могу сказать. Но вот то что там бесплатно и что оно работает - могу подтвердить. А вот гугл платен и все способы обхода - нелегальны

Comment: @ЮрийСПб яндексный апи постоянно падает или же вообще не работает. Там половина рест методов битые

Comment: @Санаев, возможно Я его только для перевода релиз-нотов на CI использую. Т.е. мало и проблем не видел.

Comment: MS-овский тоже неплохой, юзал давно, проблем не было https://github.com/iamjoshuabcxvii/MSTranslateAPIforAndroid